# Launch Independent Python Process From PHP

Tags: php, python, linux, apache, yii

I have a task requiring me to work with massive data sync which PHP cannot handle due to short execution time of the script. The Option I have is to launch a Python script and let PHP terminate (with such message as "Successfully Done" to user). I have tried all Options I could find here at SO and elsewhere I found via google but none works.

After I failed the first attempt I came up with this Idea, my PHP script will launch the first Python script (lets call it `testcmd.py`). They Python script will then launch and independent process (lets call it `thecommand.py`) that is not tied to it (something like detached threads do) and terminate. This will avoid hanging PHP script at the same time accomplish what I want

Unfortunately, am yet to find a way of independently launching `thecommand.py` from `testcmd.py`
I have tried many things but here is my current code. If you have better Idea on how to do it, I will be happy to go that route.

***run_command.php***

```
$cmd = "./testcmd.py"; 
$output = [];
exec("$cmd 2>&1", $output, $return_status);
print_r($output);  
echo $return_status;
```

***testcmd.py***

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
import subprocess
import sys

# some code here
print "Launching Command"
#proc = Popen([cmd_str], shell=True,
#             stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, close_fds=True)
pid = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "/path/to/file/no/spaces/in/path/thecommand.py"], stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, close_fds=True) # call subprocess
```

***thecommand.py***

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import json
import urllib2

url = 'http://some/api/url/here/2'
data = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
js =  json.JSONDecoder().decode(data) 
for user in js: 
    print js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the approach used to do this type of task is to have a background "worker" thread running that periodically checks a "work queue". They worker then handles things as needed (and doesn't need to have launch a sub thread, as it isn't limited on execution time by the web server).

So try starting with that. Your queue can be in your db and your background job can be a cronjob that checks every minute (or 5, etc).

This also means you don't **need** to launch a Python script but can use another PHP script if that works better with your business logic.

Comment: so basically you say to cron a job that runs at let say 5 minutes which then checks the db entry and once its done marks somehow? How Such periodic check let say after 5minutes add to server load? I guess none but would like to hear

Comment: That's correct re marking the entry in the db. Re server load, it isn't that much, as if there is nothing to be handled, then the process just can just exit. The only difference between my suggestion and what you were thinking is the regular launch time. Other than that, your process execution would be where most load occurs. And that will happen regardless.